# Allow multiple remote connections to an ssh Dynamic forwarded port

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

Let us assume I have three machines

A - Server to which I am sshing to
B - Client from which I am sshing
C - Another Client in B's subnet

Now, I set up dynamic port forwarding for port 1235 by executing this in Client B

```
ssh -D 1235 a@A
```

where a is the username at server A.

Now, I can connect to this port 1235 only from B as it is bound to localhost. If I modify the command as

```
ssh -D C:1235 a@A
```

then only C can connect to the port 1235 of B and not B itself. There is a third option I could use, namely

```
ssh -D 0.0.0.0:1235 a@A
```

whereby both B and C can connect to the port 1235 of B, but so can all the other machines in the same subnet as B and C. What I really want is a way to bind the dynamic port to allow only B and C to connect to it and not any other machine. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-g` option with SSH and then configure firewall rules to only allow C to connect to the port.

```
-g      Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports.
```

The command would then be:

```
ssh -g -D 1235 a@A
```

Comment: What you suggest would definitely work, but would involve playing with firewall rules, which I was hoping to avoid. One other simpler way would be to define two dynamic ports one for each address. But, I was seeing if there is a way to bind two addresses to a single dynamically forwarded port without the need of any firewall modifications.

Answer (score 0):

SSH itself doesn't check source IP addresses under any circumstances, to my knowledge (they can be spoofed anyway). So you'd probably have to use a packet filter on B (e.g. iptables) and set it up so that incoming TCP packets with destination port 1235 must have B as their source address.